# Failed to Set Breakpoint in WinDbg

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

My workflow follows.

1. Configure the symbol file path and source code file path for WinDbg.
2. Open one source code file to be debugged later.
3. Press F9 and try to set breakpoint in the source code.
4. WinDbg pops up an error dialog, saying 'Debuggee must be stopped before breakpoints can be modified.'

Who can tell me why? My WinDbg version is 6.11.0001.404 (X86), Windows XP 64-bit. I am debugging a dll from within very complicated runtime system.

I wrote a simple exe and click  to open it. Immediately after opening it, I open the source code file and set one breakpoint. It works in this case!

Comment: Are you sure that your DLL is loaded when you are setting a breakpoint?

Comment: Sure. The target processs is alive and can be seen when I clicking the <Attach to Process> menu item.

Comment: If you can modify the source code, add __asm int 3 before where you need to break.

Answer (score 5):

The hint is in the error, "Debuggee must be stopped before breakpoints can be modified". You have to break into the target process with Debug->Break before WinDBG will let you set a breakpoint. When you launch an EXE under WinDBG is starts off broken in, so you can set the breakpoint.

-scott